# how to edit the automatic response email via email through virtuemart joomla

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

On an ecommerce website after a user selects an item and goes through the purchase process, at the end of the transaction after everything is done, the seller and buyer both receive a notification email addressing their information and what was purchased.

Where can I edit this in joomla, virtuemart? I have been searching for the file for the last hour and can’t seem to find it. Any help is appreciated.

I am using joomla cms 2.0.18a and virtuemart 2.0 (new version)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files you want are located under `components/com_virtuemart/views/invoice/tmpl`:

```
mail_html.php for the genral rules of the email (background color, for example)
mail_html_header.php
mail_html_footer.php
mail_html_shopper.php (this is the one for the order number, etc)
mail_html_shopperaddresses.php (this is the one for the block with the 2 addresses information)
mail_html_vendor.php (for the vendor email, the one you get)
mail_html_invoice_items.php (this is the one for the table with all the items, sku, prices, etc)
```

Answer extracted fom here:

http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=102633.0

Comment: Thank you jordan, sorry i am fairly new to this. Do you know how i can change the sellers address information?

Comment: I would think that is dynamically pulled from the VirtueMart setups. Is this a multi tenant setup or just a single site? Also, you might try 'mail_html_header.php'

Comment: It is a clone from another site that is in a different language, but the email and contact need to be different. I setup the virtuemart from the CMS to the correct email and contact but it hasn't updated. Maybe i need to change it with in the DB or somewhere else perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it should be stored in MySQL and pulling that info in. If you have access to MySQL admin I would look in there. Just have to check the tables I think there about about 40 related to VirtueMart.

Comment: i am looking in the php-admin right now, do you know what it may be called by any chance? thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: found it! virtuemart_vendors

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found it. ;)